# Help understanding norm in $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathbb{R}) $ and unbounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

if $f \in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathbb{R} ) $ is discontinuous at $0$ in $X$ , show that ${x_n} \rightarrow 0 $ with $f(x_n)=1$  for all n.

---

Since $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ then $||f||=+ \infty $, but I need to find ${x_n} \rightarrow 0 $ with $f(x_n) = 1$ 
$\forall n$ I don't get it here...

is $||f||=sup_{||x||=1} |f(x)|$ ?

I have find that $x_n= \frac{1}{\sum f(xn)} \rightarrow 0$ if $f(x_n)=1$ for all n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is an unbounded linear operator, we can find a sequence $\{y_n\}_n \subseteq \{y\in X\mid \lVert y\rVert \le 1\}$ such that $|f(y_n)| \rightarrow \infty$. Let $x_n = \frac{y_n}{f(y_n)}$, then $f(x_n) = 1$ and $\lVert x_n\rVert \le \frac 1{|f(y_n)|}$. Since $\frac 1{|f(y_n)|} \rightarrow 0$, $x_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: sorry I don't understand why f(x_n)=1 for all n but |f(y_n)| diverge

Comment: @Alexei $f$ is linear so $f(x_n) = (f(y_n))/f(y_n) = 1$.